# HTML5 / JavaScript game solution focusing on connectivity between server and client

Tags: game-engine

Considering the simple-graphic turn-based games such as **card games**, **backgammon**, ... we can see **most** of them are still developed using *Flash* or other plugin-based solutions instead of pure **JavaScript** (Ajax/WebSocket).

I want to know what is the reason? Is the connectivity between a flash game and the server more reliable than the connectivity between JavaScript API (Ajax/WebSocket) and the server?

If no, why is the reason that still most of the card games (let say those we can see on Facebook) are developed using Flash?

Comment: I've never used Flash - but it seems to me that it has many advantages(speed, built-in graphics optimisations, cross-browser compatibility) that HTML5 and the browsers themselves can't achieve at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target audience of Facebook-games is very wide, from people with the latest and greatest technology to people who are still using Windows XP with IE8.

As you will almost definitely know, IE8 does not support newer technologies such as websockets/HTML5. It is even troublesome in IE9. Thus, the developers of the Facebook games build their games in Flash as that is a technology which will run in both older versions of IE and in the latest versions of Google Chrome. They can target a much bigger audience using Flash as when they were using HTML5.

Comment: So there is no other advantage related to reliability of HTTP/Socket connection in Flash compare to XMLHttpRequest?